# Unexpected outputs are coming by only changing the data type

Tags: c++, data-structures, long-integer, unsigned, unsigned-integer

```
unsigned long long int s=0;
s=191689628 +646033877 +109099622 +798412961 +767677318+ 190145527 +199698411;
cout<<s<<endl;

return 0;
```

Output to above code is 18446744072317341664.

```
unsigned long int s=0;

s=191689628 +646033877 +109099622 +798412961 +767677318+ 190145527 +199698411;
cout<<s<<endl;

return 0;
```

OUTPUT to above code is 2902757344, this is the correct value.

why unsigned long long int is giving an unpleasant output?

Comment: What happens in the first scenario if you add `ULL` suffixes to each of the numbers?  Or in the second scenario, adding `UL` to each of the numbers?  The [**undefined behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/4641116) causes the program to crash on my machine.

Comment: gcc gives one a hint: `warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]` and produces 18446744072317341664 for both declarations.

Comment: I suppose that @Eljay is right about `ull` stuff. The 191689628 and all other numbers are _signed integers_ 4 bytes long. The compiler adds 'em together, the sum is greater than the capacity of 32-bit signed integer so an overflow occurs. The `s` is assigned _after_ overflow has occurred. Adding a `ull` or `ul` to the first number prevents overflow since the compiler first allocates 64-bit unsigned integer and adds the rest.

Comment: @Suthiro "*and produces 18446744072317341664 for both declarations*" - that would be true only if `long` is 64bit in size. Not if it is 32bit in size, which is clearly true in the OPs case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) are using the `int` type, so the result of `191689628 + 646033877 + 109099622 + 798412961 + 767677318 + 190145527 + 199698411` exceeds the highest `int` value and thus overflows.  *Signed* integer overflow is *undefined behavior*.

You are then assigning the overflowed values (which are *negative*) to *unsigned* types, which result in huge values for their respective types. `unsigned long long int` is (typically) larger than `unsigned long int`, so the difference is going to be much greater. That is why you are seeing these results.

To avoid the overflow, use *unsigned* literals to begin with.

In the first example, add the `ull` or `ULL` suffix to each literal to make them all `unsigned long long int` instead of `int`:

```cpp
unsigned long long int s = 0;
s = 191689628ULL + 646033877ULL + 109099622ULL + 798412961ULL + 767677318ULL + 190145527ULL + 199698411ULL;
cout << s << endl;
```

In the second example, use the `ul` or `UL` suffix instead:

```cpp
unsigned long int s = 0;
s = 191689628UL + 646033877UL + 109099622UL + 798412961UL + 767677318UL + 190145527UL + 199698411UL;
cout << s << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/kavDXa)